# WCF data service not responding with json, only xml

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, wcf, service

I am trying to consume a data service function with a jquery ajax call, I've tried many ways of calling it, and setting up the Service Contract and Data Service, but no matter what it keeps giving me XML. I have heard some people say I need to use jsonp, but is this really necessary?

```
 [ServiceContract]
 public interface IService1
 {

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}


// Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    bool boolValue = true;
    string stringValue = "Hello ";

    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
}
```

this is my data service class

```
 public class MyService : DataService<MyEntities>
{
    private readonly MyEntities _dataSource;

    public MyService() : this(new MyEntities()) { }

    // im doing DI since I am testing my service operations with a local DB
    public MyService(MyEntities dataSource)
    {
        _dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    protected override MyEntities CreateDataSource()
    {
        return _dataSource;
    }

    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Teams", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
    }
```

}

and this is the jquery ajax. It only alerts the error, and when I inspect errors in the console, its a json parse error because its getting XML.

```
var url = "http://localhost:2884/MyService.svc/Teams";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    accept: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("error : " + xhr + ajaxOptions + thrownError);
            }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the accept header? That's what most OData services will use to determine what type of content to render back?

Comment: I did, and by default its set to json, Still dosent work :/ Ill paste what it is now Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

Comment: you should maintain endpoint of json responce

Comment: I'm not sure what that means

Comment: I think my solution is to switch to Web API lol :D looks like thats what im going to be doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is stuck at this point in WCF Data Services, then is easy to assume you are just getting started, as I was.

My solution to this problem, was to move away from WCF, and to Web API (Microsoft seems to be doing the same) Reference: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/341414/WCF-or-ASP-NET-Web-APIs-My-two-cents-on-the-subjec

Plus look how much simpler things are, and I was able to get it working within a few minutes.

```
public class TeamsController : ApiController
{
    Team[] teams; // defined by whatever persistant means u want. ie. Entity Framework.

    public IEnumerable<Team> GetAllTeams()
    {
        return teams;
    }
}
```

Then my JS

```
 $.getJSON("api/teams/",
        function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
```

Yep this is much better :D I used this tutorial
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api